# Check if statement twice

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I am trying to find the best way to check if statement twice without rewriting my code to use loops if possible. I have this code,

```
if something == True:
    #do stuff
else:
    if something_else():
        **#this is the condition I want to check again in 30-60 seconds and if it's still true then #do stuff**

    else:
        #do stuff
```

Comment: Use a `while` loop

Comment: I was thinking using time.sleep(30) then check it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only checking twice then just write a function and call it twice. you could use a sleep function for the wait.

```
import time

def check():
    if (1==1): #check goes here
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

if check(): #check 1
    print("check 1")
    time.sleep(5) #wait
    if check(): #check 2
        print("check 2")
```